# Access-control-allow-origin header not set

Tags: cors, hapi.js

I'm trying to enable cors on my api routes :

```
const server = Hapi.server({
  port: 3003,
  host: 'localhost',
  routes: {
    log: {
      collect: true
    },
    cors: {
      origin: ['http://localhost:8080'],
      additionalHeaders: ['accept-language', 'accept-encoding', 'connection', 'origin', 'host', 'user-Agent', 'access-control-request-headers']
    }
  }
});
```

I have added additional headers but it doesn't trigger the setting of the 'Access-control-allow-origin header'.

Here are the request headers:

```
 host: 'localhost:3003',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'user-agent':
   'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'x-access-token',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks.

Comment: How is origin 'http://localhost:8080'? it should be 'http://localhost:3003'.

Comment: Well, 'origin' isn't supposed to be the origin of the request (localhost:8080) ?

Comment: The above code works fine on my computer, I have tried it with all latest version of node  and Hapijs.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Indeed, it works fine ! I forgot a '/' in my route path '-_- Anyway, thank you !